# The public function call is not getting executed after the code of private variable

Tags: php, loops

```
<?php

/* example for access specifiers*/

class myClass
{
    var $car = "alto"; //if we declare as var it is automatically considered as public
    public $pub = "alphanso"; //even no need to using public keyword  as it is public bydefault
    private $pri = "zen";

    public function myPublic()
    {
        echo "I'm public...can be accessible everywhere";

    }

    private function myPrivate()
    {
        echo "I'm private...no where am accessible,except in current class";

    }

}

$accss = new myClass;

echo $accss->car . "<br>";

echo $accss->pub . "<br>";

echo $accss->pri . "<br>";

$accss->myPublic();

$accss->myPrivate(); //visible only in the class where it is declared.


?>
```

Comment: what is the problem / question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a `private` member or a method outside of the class, trying to do that will raise a **FATAL** error.

It cannot access `$accss -> myPublic();`  because you encounter a FATAL error here `echo $accss -> pri."<br>";` as per the above condition I specified.

So the rest of the code will not be executed.

Comment: thank you. i thot of anyways the public function visible,wherever it is called.